# Что-то изменилось(,) или мне кажется?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, ссп, или, вопросительное-предложение

Я правильно понимаю, что в этом предложении запятая не нужна?

*Что-то изменилось(,) или мне кажется?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю, в таком предложении запятая не нужна:
*Что-то изменилось **или** мне кажется?*

[**Запятая в сложносочиненном предложении**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133) (Розенталь):

> **3.** Запятая перед соединительным и разделительным союзами в сложносочиненном предложении не ставится, если в его состав в качестве частей входят:
> **1)** вопросительные предложения: *Это кто такие **и** что им надобно?* (П.) — объединяет вопросительная интонация; *Который теперь час **и** сколько времени осталось до отхода поезда?; Когда состоится конференция **и** какова повестка дня?; Вы придёте ко мне **или** мне прийти к вам?*

При рассмотрении разных предложений было много дискуссий насчёт корректности применения этого правила. Чаще говорилось о длине частей и невозможности их объединения в одну интонационную фразу. А также об их семантической "несовместимости".
Здесь же мы имеем дело с короткими предложениями, которые легко можно прочитать на одном дыхании, к тому же они объединены и смыслом: *Что-то изменилось или мне кажется [, что что-то изменилось]? Что-то изменилось или [это] мне кажется?*

Answer (score 1):

**ДИАЛОГ**

— Я бы поставила запятую, потому что хочу логически подчеркнуть левую часть: ***Что-то изменИлось,** // или мне кАжется?*

— Запятую ставить **нельзя!!**  Общая вопросительная интонация.

— У меня **тоже интонация,** пауза подчеркнутая. А что можно?

— Точку, многоточие. Или вопросительный знак уберите.

**Пояснение**

Дело здесь не только **в структуре.** Думаю, что **по семантике** предложение делится **на две части**, и здесь два ударения (на каждой фразе):

*Что-то **(действИтельно)** изменилось, // или мне так кАжется?*

Но правила  **категорически запрещают!**  Как говорится, запятую ставить себе дороже – ошибка обеспечена.

Comment: Уже есть ответ, который мне помог, но плюс поставлю.

Comment: Спасибо, не ожидала)  Тогда от меня вам голос за вопрос

Answer (score 1):

> Я правильно понимаю, что в этом предложении запятая не нужна?
>
> *Что-то изменилось(,) или мне кажется?*

Если пишущий хочет дать понять читающим, что **первая часть предложения** должна быть прочтена  **с вопросительной интонацией**, то возможны, по-моему, только такие варианты:

*Что-то изменилось или мне кажется?*

*Что-то изменилось? Или мне кажется?*